# express 4.9 bodyparser req.body.name empty

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am implementing a contact form using express 4.9 and nodemailer, but I can't seem to capture the req.body. Email with had-coded values works fine. I read about using bodyParser, so I added it (what I think is before) routes. Still it does not seem to pick up req.body. May be I am missing something in the form?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, Mike

My setup is as follows:

my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));  
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var routes = require('./app_server/routes/index');
// routes for the different pages
app.use('/', routes);
```

my routes; index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrl_contact = require('../controllers/contact');

router.post('/contact', ctrl_contact.mail);

module.exports = router;
```

and the controller contact.js

```
// function to send email from contact form
module.exports.mail = function (req, res) {

    console.log('testing');
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(req.body.subject);

    // etc BUT HERE req.body is already {}
}
```

my form looks like

```
           <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12  controls">
                        <label>Subject<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" required data-validation-required-message="Subject.">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                        <label>Message<span>*</span></label>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form inputs need a `name` attribute for bodyparser to pick up.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name"id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
```